# Add an argument to nginx redirect, only if it's not already defined

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am redirecting users based on their location, using nginx. I want to add an argument to the query string only if that argument isn't already defined -- if it is defined, I don't want to change it. The argument is called `tag`.

This was my first attempt. I was hoping that it would fall to the second location if it had the `tag=` string in the URL anywhere, fall to the third if it had a querystring but was missing `tag`, and fall to the first if there was no querystring at all.

```
location / {
        return 302 https://$local_site$request_uri?tag=mytag;
}
location /tag=/g {
        return 302 https://$local_site$request_uri;
}
location /\?/ {
        return 302 http://$local_site$request_uri&tag=mytag;
}
```

Then I learned that you can't see the querystring when drilling down by location. And I've also learned that if is evil.

Is there a way to do this without using if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nginx `location` entries match only URI part of the URL, not the query strings. You might achieve what you are looking after with `map`. The following needs to be in `http` block:

EDIT: My original answer had an issue with duplicate `tag` entries in resulting URL. The original solution is at the end of the post, this is a fixed version

```
map $args $newargs {
    default $args&tag=mytag;
    ~ ^(.*)(tag=[^&]+)(.*)$ $1$2$3;
}
```

And then you would have the following `location` block:

```
location / {
    rewrite (.*) $1?$newargs temporary;
}
```

We use the `map` feature to define `$newargs` from `$args` variable, which contains the query string in the URL. The default option is to append `&tag=mytag` to the string.

If the query string contains `tag=something` string, then we simply copy the query string to a new request.

Finally, we use the `$newargs` variable as the query string in the `rewrite` destination.

This is the original answer:

```
map $arg_tag $tag {
    default $arg_tag;

    ~ ^$ mytag;
}
```

And then you would have the following `location` block:

```
location / {
    return 302 https://$local_site$request_uri?tag=$tag;
}
```

Here we first make a mapping from `tag` query argument into `$tag` variable. First line sets the default to the query argument value. The second line tests if the argument is empty, and sets `$mytag` as the value if it is.

Then you can use the `$tag` variable anywhere with the values mapped like you described.

Comment: But there will be two `tag` arguments

Comment: Do you mean like `https://example.com/uri?tag=1&tag=2`?

Comment: yes. Also, I'm not sure that `return` will replace `?` with `&`

Comment: What confuses me about this answer is that it doesn't seem to deal with any of the ?/& stuff. And does it drop all the query keys other than tag, or does it keep them all and duplicate the tag key?

Comment: I updated the answer with an alternative approach that should not have the issue with duplicate `tag` key. nginx generates `$arg_` variable for every variable in the query string, so one does not need to take care of `?` / `&` characters here. The original answer preserved all query string variables, as those are included in `$request_uri`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `if` should be avoided, but that doesn't mean you must not use it.

```
location / {
    if ($arg_tag) {
        return 302 https://$local_site$request_uri;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*) https://$local_site$1?tag=mytag;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Two followup questions: Is this an okay place to use `if`, and why use a rewrite instead of a return the second time?

Comment: One further thing -- does this drop all the arguments other than tag?

Comment: `rewrite` preserves query args.

Comment: Here we don't use any other directives except rewrite module ones (`rewrite` and `return`) so it's safe to use `if`. We just send redirect and stop processing request.